# $\frac{2019(x^{4}+2)}{x^{2}y+1} \in \mathbb{N^*}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, quadratics

Find all pair $(x;y)$ of positive integers such that $k=\frac{2019(x^{4}+2)}{x^{2}y+1} \in \mathbb{N^*}$
$\Leftrightarrow 2019x^4-kyx^2+4038-k=0$.
Hence $\Delta\geqslant 0$
$\Leftrightarrow k^2y^2+4 \cdot 2019(k-4038)\geqslant 0\Leftrightarrow y^2\geqslant \frac{4 \cdot 2019(4038-k)}{k^2}$
$$x^2y+1 \mid 2019(x^2-2y)$$
I don't know what I should do next. Help me, please?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore Yes, it is

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.  I misread 4 times 2019 as a decimal 4 point 2019.